# A question about partitioning the unit cube into simplexes

Tags: geometry, simplicial-stuff

Let $C$ be the unit cube in $\mathbb{R}^n$.  I want to simplicize $C$ (i.e. partition it into simplexes), but I have to follow these two rules:

1. I can't add any vertices to $C$.  The vertices of each simplex in the partition must be $n+1$ of the $2^n$ vertices in $C$.
2. A hyperplane is "positively-oriented" if its normal vector $v$ satisfies $v \ge 0$ (i.e. $v_1 \ge 0, \dots, v_n \ge 0$)  or $v \le 0$.  The second requirement is that every face of every simplex in the partition must be positively oriented.

Note that every face of $C$ is positively-oriented.

It's easy to do this for $\mathbb{R}^2$: divide the square with a line from its northwest corner to its southeast corner.

Can it always be done in $n$ dimensions?  Or can we prove that it is sometimes impossible?

Comment: There is a triangulation of the $n$-cube satisfying condition (1): it is what is obtained by considering the simplicial set $(\Delta^1)^n$. I haven't thought about (2).