# How to divide a unit space into many simplices?

Tags: general-topology, euclidean-geometry, simplex, simplicial-stuff, simplicial-complex

I'm sorry, it may be simple and stupid but I didn't find any relative solutions on the Internet.

Given the unit hypercube $C$ in the Euclidean space $R^n$, how to divide (or we can say "partition", I hope they have identical meanings in this aspect) $C$ into $m$ **equilateral** $n$-simplices, where $m$ is a user predefined parameter that can be an **any** large number?

Note that:

(1) We should divide $C$ as much as possible, which means the left "offcut" space (that cannot be fitly divided) should be minimal. So we need to carefully choose the edge length $l$.

(2) Any two closest $n$-simplices must be joint. They have joint vertexes, joint edges, joint faces and other joint high dimensional elements. In addition, the joint faces and joint high dimensional elements must also be simplices, e.g., the joint face with 3 joint vertexes is a 2-simplex with edge length $l$, the joint tetrahedron with 4 joint vertexes is a 3-simplex with edge length $l$, and so on in higher dimensional space.

(3) As we describes it above, we try to make **all the vertices equally distributed**. It requires all the simplices try to have the same edge length and volume. In this way, the distances from all the points to their nearest neighbors are uniform.

(4) The number of divided simplices $m$ is large enough. Its exact constraints may be related to the number of nearest neighbors that is discussed below. Let's just simply assume $m$ is a very large number. It's predefined and can be changed in different trial, which means the final algorithm should hold any large $m$ instead of only working on some specific values of $m$.

I have a naive idea for it. Since we can calculate the volume $V$ of each simplex (I suppose $V$ is a function $V(l)$ in terms of $l$), we can build the equation $\frac{1}{m}=V(l)$ and solve the $l$. Then we can start from the geometry center $O$ of cube $C$, around $O$ we can add vertexes layer by layer. For example, for $n=2$, there are 6 nearest vertexes and 6 second nearest vertexes and so on. For $n=3$, there may be 20 nearest vertexes and 20 second nearest vertexes and so on. I can't imagine the case for $n>3$. Therefore, if the idea works, the new question arises here is:

(#) Given vertex $O$, how to calculate its number of nearest neighbor vertexes for any $n$ in such case? Is there any theory indicating it?

To explain "6 nearest vertexes and 6 second nearest vertexes" for $n=2$, I give an example in the following figure. For the center red point, it has 6 nearest  blue vertexes, 6 second nearest green vertexes and 6 third nearest yellow vertexes, and we can do it continuously if $m$ is large enough.
[image: An example for n=2 and m>6]

I found a question with similar description but different purpose [A question about partitioning the unit cube into simplexes](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/371269/a-question-about-partitioning-the-unit-cube-into-simplexes).

I'm looking for a feasible algorithm to implement it. I guess it may be related into surface triangulation and Simplicial Complex. But I'm not familiar with $n$-dimensional topology and I don't know the naive idea is right or not. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps you can clarify your example for $n=2$, you lost me at "there are $6$ nearest vertices". For example, how would you do this for $n=2$ and $m=3$?

Comment: There are certainly triangulations of an n-cube, and I think they should result in simplices all with the same volume. Will they be congruent? Not sure. To obtain one, work by induction: the 1-cube is already a simplex. The 2-cube can be cut into 2 triangles. To triangulate the $n$-cube, assume it's been cut into $k$ $n$-simplices for some $k$, and then triangulate each of those (e.g., by the method described on p. 112 of Hatcher's algebraic topology book http://pi.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/ATpage.html). In particular, this gives $n+1$ pieces, so by induction you can see that $k=n!$.

Comment: @Lee Mosher, sorry, my mistake. More exact description is required additional constraints on _m_. I already re-edited the question. Hopefully it's getting a bit clearer.

Comment: @John Palmieri, I think I got your idea but it seems not the solution I'm looking for. I got several question marks: when we do this way, 1) the number of pieces is limited, I cannot arbitrarily set it. 2) "The 2-cube can be cut into 2 triangles", but the 2 triangles are not simplices if they are fitly divided (because it will be 2 right triangles). If the 2-cube is not necessarily cut in a fit way, why don't us try to cut it into more parts?

Comment: @John Palmieri, 3) I don't quite get "triangulation" meaning here, especially how we cut a 3-cube, since we need to cut the 3-cube into several 3-simplices (tetrahedrons). I'm confused about the induction process.

Comment: @Aloner Any triangle is a 2-simplex. Are you requiring equilateral triangles?

Comment: @Aloner I made a mistake in my first response. I meant it to work like this: if you have a square divided into two triangles, $T_1$ and $T_2$, then to subdivide a cube, subdivide $T_i \times [0,1]$ for each $i$ into 3-simplices, using Hatcher’s description. I forgot to say to take the product with $[0,1]$ at each stage of the induction.

Comment: @John Palmieri, yes, I'm looking for equilateral n-simplices. The previous description was a bit ambiguous and I corrected it. So based on your idea, I suppose we will get a series of "right angle" n-simplices, which is incongruent from the requirements.

Comment: Is it a difficult problem and should I ask it in a forum full of mathematicians?LOL:)